# jQuery: if content changes to some text, do something

Tags: jquery

I want to hide/show Y div, based on content of X div, but X div is populated after page load (through jQuery). How can I detect this content change with jQuery.

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve (not working):

https://codepen.io/aida-stamo/pen/GXmVgW

```js
$('#field-first-div').change(function() {
  $('#first-div').text($(this).val());
});

// what I want to happen but is not happening

if ($("#first-div").text() == 'first-value') {
  $("#second-div").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field-first-div" name="field-first-div">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first-value">first-value</option>
  <option value="second-value">second-value</option>
</select>


<div id="first-div"></div>
<div id="second-div">second div content</div>
```

**Please don't mark this as duplicate. I looked through other similar questions, but cannot find an answer as they either perform the action on an already loaded content, or deal with select tag.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) event:

```js
var first = $('#first-div'),
  second = $("#second-div");

$('#field-first-div').change(function() {
  first.text($(this).val());
});

// this will check if any changes happen to the contents of the first div:
first.on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'first-value') {
    second.hide();
  } else {
    second.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field-first-div" name="field-first-div">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first-value">first-value</option>
  <option value="second-value">second-value</option>
</select>


<div id="first-div"></div>
<div id="second-div">second div content</div>
jquery
```

Although it seems that has been deprecated in favour of the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
var targetNode = $('#first-div');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  subtree: false
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
      if (targetNode.text() === 'first-value') {
        $('#second-div').hide();
      } else {
        $('#second-div').show();
      }
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode[0], config);


$('#field-first-div').change(function() {
  targetNode.text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field-first-div" name="field-first-div">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first-value">first-value</option>
  <option value="second-value">second-value</option>
</select>

<div id="first-div"></div>
<div id="second-div">second div content</div>
```

Comment: @aliengirla.k.a.alienno.155 please see edit - didn't realise  DOMSubtreeModified has been deprecated and doesn't work in some browsers

Comment: @Pete What if i just want to monitor a change in content of span "once". e.g `<span class="basket_amount">65.70</span>` 
i.e Do something if 65.70 changes to anything else.

Comment: If you are using the MutationObserver, you can stop the observer after you run the code you want by doing `observer.disconnect();`

Comment: @Pete Thanks. Finally used `$(function(){
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(e) {//Do Something});
observer.observe($('.basket_amount')[0], {characterData: true, childList: true});
});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `if` condition inside the `change` function to make the second `div` hide on selecting the value of the select box:

```js
$('#field-first-div').change(function() {
  $('#first-div').text($(this).val());
  if ($("#first-div").text() == 'first-value') {
    $("#second-div").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field-first-div" name="field-first-div">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="first-value">first-value</option>
  <option value="second-value">second-value</option>
</select>


<div id="first-div"></div>
<div id="second-div">second div content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that it works only the first time. If I change the option to second-value, the second div stays hidden.